# Best way to dynamically add multiple abstract class instances to inheriting class instance

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

I spent quite a bit of time looking for an answer to this question but am unsure of even what it is exactly that I'm looking for. I may even be approaching this entirely wrong by using abstract classes so clarification in any way will be helpful.

I want to allow users to add multiple symptoms and treatments to a single disease from within the form template. With my limited knowledge, the only way I can imagine making this work is by having the maximum expected number of symptom and treatment model fields already defined i.e.:

```
class Symptoms(models.Model):
    symptom_one = models.CharField(max_lenth=20)
    symptom_one_severity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    symptom_two = models.CharField(max_lenth=20, blank=True)
    symptom_two_severity = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    etc.
```

This is what I currently have:

Models.py

```
class Symptoms(models.Model):
    symptom = models.CharField(max_lenth=20)
    symptom_severity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Treatments(models.Model):
    treatment = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Diseases(Symptoms, Treatments):
    disease = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Forms.py

```
class DiseaseForm(ModelForm):
    model = Diseases
    fields = (
        'symptom',
        'symptom_severity',
        'treatment',
        'disease',
    )
```

My proposed method isn't very DRY so I'm wondering **what is the best way to dynamically add multiple abstract models to an inheriting class?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement, I would propose have a Disease model with many to many to fields to Symptoms and Treatments model. [Read more about django model relationships here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#relationships). So your models should look like,

```
class Symptoms(models.Model):
    symptom = models.CharField(max_lenth=20)
    symptom_severity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Treatments(models.Model):
    treatment = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Diseases(Symptoms, Treatments):
    disease = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    symptoms = models.ManyToManyField(Symptoms)
    treatments = models.ManyToManyField(Treatments)
```